# Copy data from PostgreSQL to S3 using AWS Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-data-pipeline

I am trying to copy all the tables from a schema (PostgreSQL, 50+ tables) to Amazon S3.

What is the best way to do this? I am able to create 50 different copy activities, but is there a simple way to copy all tables in a schema or write one pipeline and loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think the old method is :

```
 1. Unload your data from PostgreSQL to a CSV file first using something like psql  
 2. Then just copy the csv to S3
```

But, AWS gives u a script to do so , `RDSToS3CopyActivity` See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/datapipeline-copy-tables/) link from AWS

Answer (score -1):

Since you have a large number of tables. I would recommend using AWS Glue as compared to AWS Data Pipeline. Glue is easily configurable having crawlers etc that allows you the flexibility to choose columns, define etc. Moreover,he underlying jobs in AWS Glue are pyspark jobs that scale really well giving you really good performance.